# htaccess problem

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

at the moment I have 2 domains pointing at the same webspace (so domain1.com/index.html and domain2.com/index.html give the same page). I'm trying to configuer it so that if I go to domain1.com/index.html or domain1.com/test/... I get forwarded to domain1.com/something/index.html or domain1.com/something/test/...

When I go to domain2.com/index.html it shouldn't get forwarded so I should just see domain2.com/index.html

Any suggestions how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is Untested:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /something/$1
```

Comment: Thanks, that does the trick, you happen to know whether this is SEO?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that but if you have domain1 live already then you will want to do a 301 redirect to the new /something/ url so that search engines recognise it as a URL that has moved rather than a duplicate. Please accept answer if it works for you.

Comment: hmm I seem to be having a couple of issues:
- I had to add a rule with www in order to www.domain1.com to work
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain1.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /something/$1

- when i now go to domain1.com I see the right page, but as soon as I click on a link I download the page (e.g. I click on a link to test.php; the browser downloads the file test.php)